# Removing the leading zeroes of a number stored in string

Tags: c

```
struct number {char digits[11];};
```

The following method removes leading zeroes from (*a).digits

```
void remove_zero(struct number *a);
```

Example: (*a).digits 000013204 ---> 13204

My approach is to define a variable b equals to (*a).digits, start seaching for the first non-zero number in b, then replace (*a).digits with the rest of b. However, I am having trouble implementing the code

```
void remove_zero(struct number *a) {
char b = (*a).digits;
while (b){   // <--- (b) indicates that it hasnt reached the terminator,right?
  if (b != '0')
    { //<-- here is where to replace (*a).digits with the rest of b, but how to?
break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 0 is not the same as '0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have an array that contains e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 | \0|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And you want it to contain

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 | 4 | \0|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

From the "images" above, it should be pretty clear that this can be done using a simple [*movement*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) of the data.

So one solution is to find the first non-zero character, and move from that to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 3):

In general it's clearer to deference a pointer to a struct and access its attributes using the `->` operator, e.g. rather than

```
char b = (*a).digits;
```

do this

```
char *b = a->digits;
```

Note that `digits` is an array of chars, so `b` needs to be an array of chars, or a pointer to a char as shown here.

So:

```
void remove_zero(struct number *a)
{
    char *b = a->digits;
    char *end = a->digits + sizeof a->digits - 1;

    while (b < end && *b == '0')
        b++;

    if (b != a->digits)
    {
        size_t n = end - b;
        memmove(a->digits, b, n);
        a->digits[n] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though to be picky, wouldn't this code invoke undefined behavior in case there are no leading zeroes? Since calling strcpy with parameters that overlap is UB. I would have written `if(a->digits != b) strcpy(...`.

Comment: @Lundin: you are absolutely right, good pickup. Strictly speaking, the parameters overlap whether there are leading zeroes or not because both are pointers to/within the same string. I've changed my answer to use `memmove()` instead and to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: I think the same string is fine, as long as not the same item in the array isn't copied to its own memory location.